# How to align vertically Skeleton button and h1?

Tags: css

I found that button inside h1 element in Skeleton isn't aligned vertically in the following snippet
https://jsfiddle.net/zzmaster/to8xcLdk/2/

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="twelve columns">
            <h2>
                <a href="#" class="button">i am button</a>
                i am header
            </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

I have a sneaking suspicion that `line-height` is the problem, but setting the equal values to h1 and to .button do not resolve this.

Comment: just set `vertical-align: middle;` to a.button

Comment: You need to tag skeleton, whatever that is. Also, your title says h1. Did you mean h2?

Comment: Rob - there is no just "skeleton" tag and I can't create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the h2 a flexbox with `align-items:center` and remove the `margin-bottom` from the a tag:

```css
h2 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

h2 a{
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="twelve columns">
        <h2>
          <a href="#" class="button">i am button</a> i am header
        </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```